# Ember FastBoot SimpleDOM body is empty

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to read from the DOM in an instance initializer in the FastBoot environment but `document.body` seems to be empty. The following code works in the browser but returns nothing in FastBoot:

```
const ELEMENT_NODE_TYPE = 1;

// TODO(maros): Get this working with FastBoot. For some reason the SimpleDOM
// body is empty.
const findBootstrapData = (document) => {
  for (let currentNode = document.body.firstChild; currentNode; currentNode = currentNode.nextSibling) {
    if (currentNode.nodeType !== ELEMENT_NODE_TYPE) {
      continue;
    }

    if (currentNode.getAttribute('class') === 'bootstrap-data') {
      return JSON.parse(currentNode.firstChild.nodeValue);
    }
  }
};

export function initialize(appInstance) {
  const store = appInstance.lookup('service:store');
  const document = appInstance.lookup('service:-document');

  const data = findBootstrapData(document);
  if (data) {
    store.push({ data: data.posts });
  }
}

export default {
  name: 'blog-posts',
  initialize
};
```

The data that I'm trying to read has been injected into the `{{content-for "body"}}` section using an Ember CLI addon. This works perfectly without FastBoot.

**How can I get this instance initializer working in FastBoot?**

---

Edit:

For extra context, here's how I'm populating the DOM using an Ember CLI Addon:

```
/* eslint-env node */
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const convertMarkdown = require('marked');
const parseFrontMatter = require('front-matter');

// Reads blog posts from `/posts`, compiles from markdown to HTML and stores
// as JSON in a script tag in the document. An instance initializer then picks
// it up and hydrates the store with it.
module.exports = {
  name: 'blog-posts',

  contentFor: function(type) {
    if (type !== 'body') {
      return;
    }

    const dirname = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'posts');
    const data = fs.readdirSync(dirname).map((filename, index) => {
      if (!filename.endsWith('.md')) {
        return;
      }

      const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(path.join(dirname, filename), 'utf-8');
      const frontMatter = parseFrontMatter(fileContent);

      return {
        id: index + 1,
        type: 'post',
        attributes: {
          title: frontMatter.attributes.title,
          body: convertMarkdown(frontMatter.body),
        },
      };
    });

    return `
      <script class="bootstrap-data" type="text/template">
        ${JSON.stringify({ posts: data })}
      </script>
    `;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.body` will always be empty during the app boot lifecycle. Since the rendering is not done yet (during the instance initializer phase), the fastboot placeholders aren't replaced.

You could do either of the following:

1. You could use the shoebox API to push and get the fastboot bootstrap data : http://ember-fastboot.com/docs/user-guide#the-shoebox
2. If you want to do it outside the app lifecycle, then you could do it after `fastboot.visit` request is done and after [result.html()](https://github.com/ember-fastboot/fastboot/blob/master/src/result.js#L20) is called.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do this outside the app lifecycle? I'm retrieving the bootstrap data in the `contentFor` hook of an addon (edited my question to include this). I'm not sure how to access Shoebox during `contentFor`.

Comment: After the build, you see the script tag in the built index.html? `contentFor` runs during the build. You basically want to use that data and populate the store and use it in your app? If so, I don't think it will be work in fastboot since DOM in fastboot is a minimal data structure. Hence `document.body` is empty and not representing the index.html body content. You would want to use fastboot's `metadata` property and access it during boot and populate the store. See this PR: https://github.com/ember-fastboot/fastboot/pull/75

Comment: Ok, `metadata` seems useful. I'm just not clear on how to use `fastboot.visit`. It's not mentioned anywhere in the [docs](https://www.ember-fastboot.com/) and I'm not currently explicitly calling it myself.